# Drag and select to return selected points in MPAndroidChart

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am working on a project and recently started using MPAndroidChart.

I have the MPAndroidChart working and correctly populating chart data but I want a way to be able to drag and select an area of the chart. Once the selection has been made it needs to returns the x values and y values of the points that was selected.

I can't see any way of doing what I want. I found this highlighting functionality in https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting but I don't think that this is the right thing that I am looking for.

Is what I am doing posssible and if so point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `OnChartGestureListener`
to listen for begin and end of a touch gesture and maybe `OnChartValueSelectedListener` or `ChartTouchListener` to catch selection events between.

To get a chart value from a `MotionEvent` supplied by the latter two listeners, you can use something like

```
chart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).getValuesByTouchPoint(me.x, me.y)
```